# Get Excel files excluding temporary files in a folder

Tags: python, glob

I need to get Excel files excluding temporary files (has ~$ in front of the file name) in a folder. Now I wrote a code that gets all the Excel files:

```
files = glob.glob('./data/*.xlsx')
```

But in this case, I can get all excel file including the temporary files. How can I exclude them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not take the list produced by your current code and remove any temporary files using:

```
>>> files = ['file.xlsx', 'anotherfile.xlsx', '~$temporaryfile.xlsx']
>>> [ x for x in files if "$" not in x ]
['file.xlsx', 'anotherfile.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
files = glob.glob('./data/[^~]*.xlsx')
```

For glob you can use unix style match patterns. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)